# Tkinter - Change Frame if correct information input

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm fairly new to Tkinter, so I may have overlooked something or made a simple error. I have two frames: A login screen and another frame with a label on it.
I want to change frames if they input the correct login details. If they input incorrect login details, then an error message is output, this works fine, however when the correct details are input nothing happens, no error, no change nothing:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class QPCSRegistration(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (LoginScreen,TestScreen):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            self.show_frame(LoginScreen)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class LoginScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.Username_label = tk.Label(self, text="Username")
        self.Password_label = tk.Label(self, text="Password")

        self.Username_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.Password_entry = tk.Entry(self, show="*")

        self.Username_label.grid(row=0, sticky="e")
        self.Password_label.grid(row=1, sticky="e")
        self.Username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.Password_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)


        self.LoginButton = tk.Button(self, text="Login", command = self.Login_Button_Clicked)
        self.LoginButton.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.pack()

    def Login_Button_Clicked(self):

        Username = self.Username_entry.get()
        Password = self.Password_entry.get()

        if Username == "Victoria" and Password == "qpcsadmin":
            lambda:controller.show_frame(TestScreen)
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect Login details")

class TestScreen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Random_label = tk.Label(self, text="Random Label")

app = QPCSRegistration()
app.mainloop()
```

Anybody have any idea why my code doesn't work? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if Username == "Victoria" and Password == "qpcsadmin":
        lambda:controller.show_frame(TestScreen)
```

Delete the `lambda` there.

```
    if Username == "Victoria" and Password == "qpcsadmin":
        controller.show_frame(TestScreen)
```

You will probably also have to save `controller` as an attribute of `self`, since otherwise it won't be accessible anywhere outside of `__init__`.

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    self.controller = controller
    #etc
def Login_Button_Clicked(self):
    #etc
        self.controller.show_frame(TestScreen)
    #etc
```